# XML to Dataframe with R

Tags: r, xml, rstudio

Hello i got xml data like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Locus Map, Android"
 xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
 xmlns:gpx_style="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_style/0/2"
 xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
 xmlns:gpxtrkx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension/v1"
 xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v2"
 xmlns:locus="http://www.locusmap.eu">
    <metadata>
        <desc>File with points/tracks from Locus Map/3.31.2</desc>
    </metadata>
<wpt lat="43.485033" lon="-74.949134">
    <ele>631.86</ele>
    <time>2018-06-25T18:14:39.850Z</time>
    <name>Fjdjxud</name>
    <pdop>2.10</pdop>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="43.485087" lon="-74.949118">
    <ele>627.29</ele>
    <time>2018-06-25T18:15:30.345Z</time>
    <name>2018-06-25 14:15:30</name>
    <pdop>2.10</pdop>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="43.485093" lon="-74.948893">
    <ele>629.72</ele>
    <time>2018-06-25T18:16:05.183Z</time>
    <name>2018-06-25 14:16:05</name>
    <pdop>2.10</pdop>
</wpt>
</gpx>
```

i need to convert this to

```
A tibble: 6 x 2
    lon   lat
   <dbl> <dbl>
1 -74.9  43.5
2 -74.9  43.5
3 -74.9  43.5
4 -74.9  43.5
5 -74.9  43.5
6 -74.9  43.5
```

i tried,

```
xmldataframe <- xmlToDataFrame("gpsdata.xml")
print(xmldataframe)
```

i search other methods but it cannot help, many of codes brings me 0 rows, i cannot convert this xml data can anyone help me pls, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
library(XML)
library(tibble)
data=htmlParse("C:/Users/.../yourxmlfile.xml")
lat=xpathSApply(data,"//@lat")
lon=xpathSApply(data,"//@lon")

lat=round(as.numeric(lat),1)
lon=round(as.numeric(lon),1)

df=as_tibble(data.frame(lon,lat))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>     lon   lat
>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 -74.9  43.5
> 2 -74.9  43.5
> 3 -74.9  43.5
> ```